# Grouping repetitions into batches in SQL

Tags: sql, grouping

i am trying to group my table per batches , each batch ends (and the next one starts) when the type is changing. data is sorted per num.
the data i have is as follows:

```
type      num
-----------------
Agent      1
Agent      2
User       3
User       4
Agent      5
User       6
User       7
```

and i am looking to add the batch number:

```
type      num    batch
----------------------
Agent      1       1
Agent      2       1
User       3       2
User       4       2
Agent      5       3
User       6       4
User       7       4
```

i have tried dense_rank and lead/lag with no success
thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `num` has no gaps, you can subtract a sequence to get a constant for each group and use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by num - seqnum, type) as batch_num
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by num) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can also use lag and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_type = type then 0 else 1 end) over (order by num) as batch_num
from (select t.*, lag(type) over (order by num) as prev_type
      from t
     ) t;
```